# How to extend the Bounds of LatLngBounds on one point out of sight?

Tags: android, google-maps, bounds, google-polyline

```
VisibleRegion vr = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
    LatLngBounds bounds = vr.latLngBounds;

    List<LatLng> visiblePassed = getVisiblePointForRegion(bounds, passed);
    List<LatLng> visibleRemain = getVisiblePointForRegion(bounds, remain);
```

I have to draw a polyline, which will go beyond appearances of map on 1 point.

```
polyoptions.addAll(visiblePassed);
        mMap.addPolyline(polyoptions);

polyoptions.addAll(visiblePassed);
        mMap.addPolyline(polyoptions);
```

This code gives me this result: http://joxi.ru/VrwQ941t6bWM2X.jpg

But I need to polyline extend beyond the screen. How to do it ? How to extend Bounds at one point?

Comment: it is not really clear what you need, what does getVisiblePointForRegion does? What are passed and remain?

Comment: Also, what do `passed` and `remain` refer to?

Comment: getVisiblePointForRegion - a method that takes the point of my polylines, compares them with the points that are visible and forms a sheet of them to draw. 
Since Bounds gives me a point within sight, my polylines over. Therefore, I would like to extend Bounds 1 point out of sight.

Comment: passed and remain - is just options for polylines. For two colours of way that user passed or have to go...